# distorted fourier transform is isometric

Tags: analysis

I need a proof for this theorem that says :

Assume that $V \in L_{1}^{1},$ and that $V$ has no bound states, then $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ is an isometry on $L^{2}$,
$$
\|\widetilde{\mathcal{F}} f\|_{L^{2}}=\|f\|_{L^{2}}, \quad \forall f \in L^{2}
$$
and $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}$ is a bijection with
$$
\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}^{-1} \phi(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x, k) \phi(k) d k
$$
Moreover, the distorded Fourier transform diagonalizes $-\partial_{x}^{2}+V:$
$$
-\partial_{x}^{2}+V=\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}^{-1} k^{2} \widetilde{\mathcal{F}}
$$

where the distorted Fourier transform is defined by
$$
\widetilde{\mathcal{F}} \phi(k)=\widetilde{\phi}(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{\psi(x, k)} \phi(x) d x
$$
$$
\psi(x, k):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
{T(k) f_{+}(x, k)} & {\text { for } k \geq 0} \\
{T(-k) f_{-}(x,-k)} & {\text { for } k<0}
\end{array}\right.
$$
and $T(k)$ is the transmission ,
and $f_{+}(x, k)$ and $f_{-}(x, k)$ defined by the requirements that $$\left(-\partial_{x}^{2}+V\right) f_{\pm}=k^{2} f_{\pm}, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \quad$$
 and $$\quad\left\{\begin{array}{l}{f_{+}(x, k) \sim e^{i x k} \quad \text { as } x \rightarrow \infty} \\ {f_{-}(x, k) \sim e^{-i x k} \quad \text { as } x \rightarrow-\infty}\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Consider, e.g., Hörmander-The analysis of linear partial differential operators II (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=705278), section 14.6, in particular Theorem 14.6.4.
(Note that $\tilde F$ isometrically (in fact, unitarily) maps $E^c L^2$ to $L^2(d\xi)$ and vanishes on $E^d L^2$ where $E^d L^2$ is spanned by $L^2$ eigenfunctions of $-\partial_x^2+V$, when $V$ is short range.)